# diferentes secciones creadas en html se ponen una al lado de la otra de manera indeseada, al usar bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Ya intente usar clear:both; para eliminar posicionamiento flotante en caso de que haya y tambien puse display:block a cada sección y aun asi los pone uno al lado del otro en lugar de abajo del otro. Mi codigo es el siguiente

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

.Bienvenidos {
  background-color: red;
  /* Si se usa background nada mas, el background tapa el texto que se ponga encima de él */
  background-image: url("../images/negocios.png");
  background-size: cover;
  /*one image that ocuppy all the window*/
  /*min-width:33vw; /* this has to be used because background-size cover doesnt reach full page
  and if you put width only, it left a little space*/
  display: block;
  /*height:100vh;*/
  /*overflow:hidden; /*en el caso de que al poner un margen la imagen no cubra toda la pantalla*/ }

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both; }

.Bienvenidos {
  /*position:relative;*/ }

.Encabezado {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  /*position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:0;*/ }

/*this part makes all the navbar go black and fixed-top makes it ocuppy all the window*/
.fixed-top {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }

.navbar-light .navbar-brand, .navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  font-size: 1.5rem; }

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .open > .nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.open, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); }

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"); }

.navbar-nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center; }

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .open > .nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.open, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  background: red; }

.nav-item:hover {
  background: red; }

.active {
  margin-top: .2rem; }

.btn-secundary, .btn-secundary:hover {
  background-color: #ff4;
  color: white; }

.nav-item {
  /*margin:.2rem;*/ }

.texto-bienvenido {
  margin-top: 6rem; }

.btn-primary, .btn-primary:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  border-color: black; }

.btn-primary, .btn-secundary {
  text-transform: Uppercase; }

.quienes-somos {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  /*position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:100vh; /*Debido a que por una extraña razon no se pudo realizar como en el video se tuvo que cambiar el position a absolute
  para que el siguiente section se encontrara abajo y no al lado, NOTA: no funciono clear:both y clearfix:after*/
  /*width:33vw;*/ }

.servicios {
  background-color: #ff8;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  /*position:absolute;
  left:0;*/
  /*width:33vw;
  /*top:256vh;*/ }

/*background-size:cover;   sirve para que la imagen llene todo su contenedor*/

/*# sourceMappingURL=estilos.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS que se descargo de la pagina y fue compilado con Koala-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body>

  <section class="Bienvenidos">
    <div class="container">
      <header class="Encabezado">


        <!-- la imagen debe estar en la misma carpeta que el archivo.css-->

        <!-- para que lo que sigue despues del menu se quede fijo le agregamos la clase navbar-fixed-top-->
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top panel-default.affix navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">   
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#!">Navbar</a>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-md-0">
              <!--ul class="menu_ext"-->
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <!-- active es para mostrar el valor que actualmente esta activo del menu-->
                <a class="nav-link" href="#!">Nosotros <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#!">Servicios</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#!">Portafolios</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#!">Contactos</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>

      </header>

      <div class="texto-bienvenido text-center">
        <p class="h4">Bienvenidos a nuestro estudio.</p>
        <h1 class="display-3 mb-3">Encantado de conocerte.</h1>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Ponte en contacto.</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

  <section class="quienes-somos py-3">
    <div class="container text-center">

      <img src="images/persona.svg" alt="persona" class="img-fluid mt-3 mb-3 "></img>
      <h2 class="h1">¿Quienes somos?<br></h2>
      <p>Ponemos un servicio integral al alcance de tus necesidades, desde la parte de frontend hasta el backend de tu sitio web de manera que sea adaptable a cualquier dispositivo movil.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secundary btn-lg mb-3">Más información.</a>

    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="servicios py-3 text-center">

    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="h1">Nuestros servicios<br></h2>

      <div class="row">
        <!-- si se usa col-* o con un tamaño especifico de pantalla la suma del numero de columnas totales no puede pasar de 12-->
        <div class="col-md-4">
          a
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          a
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          a
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

  </section>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Por alguna razón, no aparece todo el código, espero que me ayuden en eso igual. La versión de bootstrap que uso es la 4 alpha 6

Answer (score 0):

Al body le has añadido las propiedades

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
```

Para que se muestre cada `section` uno debajo del otro tienes dos opciones.

Primera opción, añadiendo la propiedad `flex-direction`:

```
body {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Segunda opción, cambiando el valor de `display`:

```
body {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, disculpa la tardanza es que elimine las propiedades que dijiste y me funcionó, pero no sabía como dejarlas y que siguiera funcionando :)

Comment: De nada. Para dejarlas y que siga funcionando sólo tendrías que añadir a esas propiedades, la propiedad flex-direction: column;. Edito la respuesta para que se entienda mejor.